# MVC parameter returning null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

Below is the **Controller** code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public string Index(string name)
    {
        return "Welcome to MVC_Demo"+name;
    }

}
```

and below is the **Global.asax.cs** codes:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

When I run the application and  browse for (http://localhost/MVC_Demo/home/index/pradeep) it shows only,
"Welcome to MVC_Demo" as the output, and not as "Welcome to MVC_Demo Pradeep"  i.e the parameter name "Pradeep" is not getting displayed.

Considering me just a beginner any help would be highly appreciated.

---

Comment: Because you method need to be `public string Index(string id)` so that you match your route (which expect a parameter named `id`). Or you need to create a specific route.

Answer (score 2):

As your route states, the default parametername is `id`. So either change the default parametername to be `name` like this

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Or you can change the name of the parameter to be `id` and match the route.

```
public string Index(string id)
{
    return $"Welcome to MVC_Demo {id}";
}
```

One more solution is to specify the parametername explicitly as a QueryString parameter:

http://localhost/MVC_Demo/home/index?name=pradeep

Comment: No problem @pradeep.